# Как правильно передать props в компонет

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Имеется компонент с методом рендер

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={ () => (this.state.loggedIn ? (<ContentLayout/>) : (<Redirect to="/login"/>))}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" render={ (props) =>  <LogonForm {...props} /> } />
                    <Route exact path="/registration" render={ (props) => <RegistrationForm {...props} /> } />
                </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Как мне в компонент LogonForm передать через props функцию?

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавьте после `...props` через запятую имя функции, если она определена локально и вы хотите ее передать под тем же именем.

Пример:

```
function foo() {...}

...
<Route exact path="/login" render={ (props) =>  <LogonForm {...props, foo} /> } />
...
```

Если же это метод или вы хотите передать функцию под другим именем, то добавляете как пару `имя:значение`.

Пример:

```
...
<Route exact path="/login" render={ (props) =>  <LogonForm {...props, foo: this.foo} /> } />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьмем за основу Ваш старый код и поменяем его под ваши нужды для пути `login`:

```
myFunc() {
   alert('Hello world!');
}

logonRender() {
  return (<LogonForm propsFunc={this.myFunc} />);
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact path="/"
            render={
              () => (this.state.loggedIn ? (<ContentLayout/>) : (<Redirect to="/login"/>))
            }
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            component={this.logonRender} 
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/registration"
            render={(props) => <RegistrationForm {...props} />}
          />
        </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Какой здесь пример:

- `myFunc` - это функция, которую мы будем передавать в компонент `LogonForm` через `props`
- `logonRender` - это функция, которая возвращает компонент `LogonForm` с заполненными `props`
- [`Route`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md) - это компонент, который умеет рендериться тремя разными способами:

  1. `<Route component>` - [рендеринг через `component`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#component) (вариант, который написан в моем коде)
  2. `<Route render>` - [рендеринг с помощью функции `render`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#render-func)
  3. `<Route children>` - [рендеринг через `children`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#children-func)

Думаю, если почитать документацию по [`Route`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md) компоненту, то все сразу станет на свои места.